# get records of San Francisco when search for 'SanF' in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Get 'San Francisco' record when I search for 'SanF';

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%san%'; Works
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%san F%'; Works
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE %sanF%'; Not Working
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid that the `LIKE` operator is not a panacea for doing textual search based queries.  If you really want to match a user input of `sanF` to records containing `San Francisco`, then you will have to remove the whitespace from the column and then do the comparison.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REPLACE(col, ' ', '') LIKE '%sanF%';
```

You could also consider doing some massaging of the user input on the application side so that your original two `LIKE` conditions (`'%san%'` and `'%san F%'`) cover every case.

Comment: to make the query work in all the above cases, you should use  `LIKE REPLACE('%sanF%',' ','');`

Comment: @ughai this won't work, because you're only replacing the needle you're searching for, and this don't even have a space inside!

Comment: @bobbel :- I am assuming the OP has the base code like this. `SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE %?%';` and replaces `?` with the appropriate search filter (3 of which is mention in the question). For a single query to work in all cases, we either strip spaces at both ends (which i suggested ) or handle the spaces in filter on the application side which mapek later suggested.

Comment: @ughai I mean, the real question is, how to find "San Francisco" when searching for "SanF" and this won't even work, if you're replacing the not existing spaces in the needle "SanF", will it?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%sanF%'; will never work for 'San Francisco'  
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REPLACE(col, ' ', '') LIKE '%sanF%';
```

is correct use.
But `REPLACE` function may slow down and you can see performance issue for large data set, even like query is costly.
People do optimize it by applying indexes on column, or by trying using `San F%` or `%Francisco`.
What we did is, instead of using like on both the side, we just performed like on single side.

Comment: "instead of using like on both the side, we just performed like on single side." statement is not fully correct as '%Francisco' will not use index as index works from left to right but not right to left.

Comment: Yes, agree, i used OR in my statement, "People do optimize it by applying indexes on column, OR by trying using 'San F%' or '%Francisco' "

Answer (score -2):

In you're php you could replace all spaces with `_`s or `%`s.
Or you could do it in the query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('San F', ' ', '%'), '%')
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE CONCAT('%', REPLACE('San F', ' ', '_'), '%')
```

Hope this helps!