# get records of 'Yosemite National Park' when search for 'yosemite Park' in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Get 'Yosemite National Park' record when I search for 'yosemite Park'.

```
 - SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%yosemite%'; Works 
 - SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%yosemite national%'; Works 
 - SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%yosemite national park%'; Works   
 - SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%yosemitenationalpark%'; Not Working      
 - SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%yosemite park%'; Not Working 
 - SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%park yosemite%'; Not Working
```

Is there any other way then please suggest?

Comment: what is your question? other way to do what?

Comment: Like is not working if we change the sequence of word.

Comment: I believe you want to be looking at `full text search` or something separate like elasticsearch.

Comment: I think this is the duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33296343/get-records-of-san-francisco-when-search-for-sanf-in-mysql]

Comment: I want result for last three queries which is not working.. Please suggest how to handle such use case.

Answer (score 1):

Like is just a regexp- it does not find words in a different order.

If you want in any order, you can do something like this (not very efficient if your table is big though):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%park%' and col like '%yosemite%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%yosemitepark%' OR REPLACE(col," ","") LIKE '%yosemitepark%'
```